# Synchronizing between different threads in Swift

Tags: swift, thread-safety

Could anyone provide advice on how to lock between threads in Swift? Specifically, I have code that separates the model from the view. The model processes adds, updates, and deletes separately before committing for the view to access. I have code that runs on the background thread to keep the main thread nice and snappy. The sample code below is similar to what I’ve implemented and it works. However, I worry that it’s overly complicated with the DispatchQueue and locks. I don’t know of a better way to lock between threads and this seems to work but I’m sure someone smarter than I can show a more elegant solution? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
class MyClass {
    private let model = MyDataModel()
    private let syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyClass")
    private let lock = NSLock()  

    /**
        This function can be called from several different places on several different threads.
    */
    func processAdds() {
        assert(!Thread.isMainThread)

        // Ensure no other thread sneaks in and modifies the model while we're working.
        syncQueue.sync {
            self.lock.lock() // Is this overkill?

            // Modify the model.
            self.model.calculatePendingAdds()

            // Commit the model.
            self.model.commit()

            // Do some long running stuff with the committed data.
            self.model.doStuff()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateTheUI() // Must be done on the main thread but we don't want another background thread sneaking in and modifying the model.

                // Only release the lock when this main thread async block is finished.
                self.lock.unlock() // I think this is not overkill because I can't exit the syncQueue before the main thread is finished updating the UI.
            }
    } 

    /**
        This function can be called from several different places on several different threads.
    */
    func processDeletes() {
        assert(!Thread.isMainThread)

        // Ensure no other thread sneaks in and modifies the model while we're working.
        syncQueue.sync {
            self.lock.lock() // Is this overkill?

            // Modify the model.
            self.model.calculatePendingDeletes()

            // Commit the model.
            self.model.commit()

            // Do some long running stuff with the committed data.
            self.model.doStuff()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateTheUI() // Must be done on the main thread but we don't want another background thread sneaking in and modifying the model.

                // Only release the lock when this main thread async block is finished.
                self.lock.unlock() // I think this is not overkill because I can't exit the syncQueue before the main thread is finished updating the UI.
            }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging around and trying some experimenting I realized using a custom dispatch queue with a lock was indeed overkill. The dispatch queue acts like a lock already so using it with a lock was redundant. I really just needed a lock that could be unlocked on a different thread so I figured a mutex was better. I got rid of the custom queue and lock and replaced it with this:

```
class MyClass {
    private let model = MyDataModel()
    private let mutex = pthread_mutex_t()

    /**
        This function can be called from several different places on several different threads.
    */
    func processAdds() {
        assert(!Thread.isMainThread)

        // Ensure no other thread sneaks in and modifies the model while we're working.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&self.mutex)

        // Modify the model.
        self.model.calculatePendingAdds()

        // Commit the model.
        self.model.commit()

        // Do some long running stuff with the committed data.
        self.model.doStuff()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateTheUI() // Must be done on the main thread but we don't want another background thread sneaking in and modifying the model.

            // Only release the lock when this main thread async block is finished.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.mutex)
        }
    } 

    /**
        This function can be called from several different places on several different threads.
    */
    func processDeletes() {
        assert(!Thread.isMainThread)

        // Ensure no other thread sneaks in and modifies the model while we're working.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&self.mutex)

        // Modify the model.
        self.model.calculatePendingDeletes()

        // Commit the model.
        self.model.commit()

        // Do some long running stuff with the committed data.
        self.model.doStuff()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateTheUI() // Must be done on the main thread but we don't want another background thread sneaking in and modifying the model.

            // Only release the lock when this main thread async block is finished.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.mutex)
        }
    } 
}
```

Seems simple and works.